# Capacity planning for back-end SQL Server 2012 for a SP 2013 Farm

Tags: sql-server-2012, capacity-planning, spfarm, back-end

Would like to know how much MB of space/how much load SQL Server has to take when we upload a 8 MB - 10 MB size of document in document library in SP 2013 site collection.

Cant we calculate as 10 MB only ? I just wanted to perform a capacity planning for a upcoming SP farm, where the number of users is 100-125 and the max. size of file is  ~ 10 MB. So how can I calculate the SQL Server details -with a single instance [ default  or named ??] like 1 Sql Server with clustering enabled on Lenovo Blade server with many drives.
am still clueless about how to come to a conclusion about these details - for back-end.

Since we dont know where and where the document resides and in what fromat sql stores the document [??] in the sql table, is there any way to calculate and arrive at some conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage depends upon multiple things, How many documents you are expecting, How many versions, metadata, list items etc.

Here is formula which MSFT mentioned in their Capacity planning guide. You can add the values accordingly and get the total estimated storage required for the SharePoint farm.

Database size = ((D × V) × S) + (10 KB × (L + (V × D)))

1. Calculate the expected number of documents. This value is known as D
   in the formula.
2. Estimate the average size of the documents that you'll be storing.
   This value is known as S in the formula.
3. Estimate the number of list items in the environment. This value is
   known as L in the formula.
4. Determine the approximate number of versions. Estimate the average
   number of versions any document in a library will have. This value
   will usually be much lower than the maximum allowed number of
   versions. This value is known as V in the formula. The value of V
   must be above zero.

Read more over here: [Storage and SQL Server capacity planning and configuration (SharePoint Server 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)